# KML Placemark Icon has different anchor point in Google Earth than when loaded in Google Maps, Why?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, google-earth

I have a KML file containing placemarks with custom icons.

When viewed in Google Earth the anchor point is center of the icon. Like this ...

[image]

When the KML file is viewed in Google Maps on my website, the anchor point changes to be the bottom center of the icon. Like this ...

[image]

Why is this? And how do I change it so that when loaded by Google Maps API the anchor point is in the center of the icon?

Here is the styling in the KML file ...

```
<Style id="Parking">
    <IconStyle><Icon><href>http://www.virtualmountains.co.uk/shared/Parking.png</href></Icon></IconStyle>
    <BalloonStyle>
        <text>$[description]</text>
        <bgColor>white</bgColor>
        <text><![CDATA[
            <font color="#674A32" face="arial" align="justify">$[description]</font>
        ]]></text>
    </BalloonStyle>
    <LabelStyle>
        <color>FFFFFFFF</color>
        <scale>0.8</scale>
    </LabelStyle>
</Style>
```

Here's the placemark code ...

```
<Placemark>
    <name>A5 Parking, Tryfan</name>
     <description>        
        <![CDATA[
            <DIV style="max-width:400px; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px; color:#674A32; font-family:Arial">
                <DIV style="font-size:11pt; font-weight:bold; text-align:left">A5 Parking, Tryfan<BR></DIV>
                <DIV style="font-size:10pt; text-align:justify"><BR>
                    There is a parking here alongside a great length of the A5.
                </DIV>
            </DIV>
        ]]>
    </description>
    <styleUrl>#Parking</styleUrl>  
    <Point><coordinates> -3.991196, 53.125136,0</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (complete KML).  Have you tried defining the anchor in the KML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps API V3 ignoring icon hotSpot tag in KML IconStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415502/google-maps-api-v3-ignoring-icon-hotspot-tag-in-kml-iconstyle)

Comment: Thanks geocodezip, seems from following the above link to duplicate issue and on to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830017?pli=1 this appears an on going bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the anchor point or "hotspot" for a Placemark's icon in the KML as part of the `<IconStyle>`. The `<hotspot>` tag allows you to specify the anchor point on the icon either using fraction (0 to 1) or pixel dimensions, in the x (left/right) and y (up/down) directions.

For example, if you want to make your icons anchor in the center of each one, you would make your IconStyle look like this:

```
<IconStyle>
  <Icon>
    <href>http://www.virtualmountains.co.uk/shared/Parking.png</href>
  </Icon>
  <hotSpot x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction">
</IconStyle>
```

That should work for KMLs both in Google Earth and in Google Maps.

You can find the documentation for the `<hotspot>` tag in the KML reference, here: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#hotspot

Comment: Should work for Google Maps, but doesn't. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830017

Comment: Thanks Christiaan, this is the code I was missing, but as geocodezip says, is not working for some reason, though I did try just in case it has been fixed.